# Как сделать автосохранение в Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Есть форма(view):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id'=>'formid'
]); ?>


<?= Html::activeTextInput($model, 'ik_co_id', ['class'=>'form-item req', 'value' => "{$_POST['ik_co_id']}"]) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>


<script>
$('#formid').on('focusout', function(){
 save();
});

function save() {
var url = $('#formid').attr('action');
var data = $('#formid').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
});
}
</script>
```

И контроллер:

```
public function actionFail()
{
    $model = new Activation();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['fail', 'id' => $model->active_id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('fail', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Данные не сохраняются.

Comment: это русскоязычный форум, вопросы и ответы на иных языках не допустимы.

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема? Не сохраняется? Что получается по итогам ajax запроса? PS: не используйте прямую задачу value - у вас тут XSS выходит

Comment: Не сохраняется @Bethrezen

Comment: В консоли что пишут по результатам ajax запроса? Может кстати csrf токен не подхватывается - тогда его вместе с data передать надо.

Comment: Я здесь добавляю первый раз, как исправить?@ReinRaus

Comment: в консоли ответ 200, как бы все срабатывает, но не сохраняет. @Bethrezen

Comment: 200 означает, что `$model->load` не прошел.

Comment: Все решил, просто аякс запрос сделал, незнаю насколько это безопасно, там метод save не срабатывал var url = $('#formid').attr('action'); var data = $('#formid').serialize(); $.ajax({     type: "POST",     url: url,     data: data, });

Answer (score 1):

```
Видимо проблема в var data = $('#formid').serialize();

И лучше писать так
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Activation();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['fail', 'id' => $model->active_id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('fail', [
        'model' => $model,
      ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы либо передаете в метод load() не верные параметры, либо не проходит валидацию на этапе сохранения, попробуйте сделать

```
$model->save(false)
```

если так запись записывается, то проблема в валидации если нет то смотрите что вы передаете в load()
а лучше сделайте

```
var_damp(Yii::$app->request->post())
```

и покажите что там